# Причина появления ошибки http сервера 429: Too Many Requests

Tags: java, парсер, jsoup

Написал парсер, проблем в принципе нет, если ставить таймаут в 2 секунды на ссылку, но хотелось бы как то ускорить процесс, такое возможно? 
Примерно после 3-4 ссылок, сервер выдает сообщение 429 Too Many Requests, ссылок до 50.

Comment: Никак. Сервер собственно и защищается от таких «парсеров»

Comment: В первую очередь обратите внимание на заголовки, которые отправляет Ваш парсер. Возможно, по каким-то критериям сервер определяет, что это не браузерный запрос. 
В Вашем случае относительно работающим способом будет использовать прокси (слать запросы с разных IP адресов) и\или запустить это дело на разных машинах и поставить побольше таймаут.

Comment: 429 появляется когда 2 страница имеют редирект на друг друга, те получается бесконечный цикл

Comment: Спасибо.... ускорил скорость парсинга, открываю 3 ссылки, ставлю таймаут в 3 секунды, вновь 3 ссылки и так далее. но надо чуть больше тестов провести, пока полет нормальный.